# how to apply global discount in odoo Point of sale

Tags: javascript, point-of-sale, odoo-10

i want to modify total amount when user click credit payment method then discount will apply and change total amount in my custom module.
example -> user add 3 product, the total amount is 2500(with tax included), then user click payment -> credit choice, then after user click validate, the payment method is credit in payment line and amount total is change into correct total amount (example discount credit is 10% then total amount is 2250), how i can change that total amount?

Answer (score 0):

In odoo10 we can apply global discount from settings. To do that follow the steps: Under **Point of Sale** go to **Settings >> Discount** in that you can see 2 radio buttons "Allow discounts on order lines only" and "Allow global discounts" in that you can choose whatever you want.In your case you may have to prefer 2nd option.

Also apart from that there is an module in default apps is : **Point of Sale Discounts** you can install that and use that also.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but i want apply discount when user pay with debit/credit card bank payment method, the amount is automatically discount it, not give new order line to give discount. i have solve this problem with develop new module,i can see the tutorial how to add global discount in this web : https://www.odoo.com/documentation/user/9.0/point_of_sale/advanced/manual_discount.html, so thank you for the answer Sr @Keval